# Is there a way to evenly distribute vertical space for open editors in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, ide, editor

I often find myself having 3 or for code editors open at the same time; I even have a 32:9 monitor specifically for the vertical space.

When you have two editor tabs open in Visual Studio 2019 and drag one, you get tools to help snap and dock the tab. Using that, the available screen space is split 50:50 so both tabs have the same width.

If you now open a third tab and try to wedge it between the first and second tab, the screen space is not split 33:33:33 but rather 25:50:25 and when trying to dock a fourth tab, the space is distributed even more unevenly.

Are there any plugins or tools out there that help fix this? I'd prefer all tabs to have the same width.

Answer (score 1):

You can try my [Task Canvas](https://vlasovstudio.com/task-canvas/) extension to open many editors at once in a separate window. It automatically distributes horizontal and vertical space between them.